# Unable to trigger Event Second Time

Tags: angular

This is my HTML Code i try to Change Button icon on each row click event But my event is fire first time
but not after that

```
<tr *ngFor="let skills of loaddata let indexOfelement=index">
                    <td style="text-align:center">
                    <span *ngIf="skills.isSelected==false">
                      {{skills.skill}}
                    </span>
                    <span *ngIf="skills.isSelected==true">
                      <input  type="text" [ngModel]="loaddata[indexOfelement].skill" class="form-control">
                    </span>
                    </td>
                    
                    <td style="text-align:center">
                      <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
                        <a  class="btn btn-info"><i class="fas" (click)="ClickToEdit(skills,indexOfelement)" [ngClass]="{'fa-edit':!loaddata[indexOfelement].isSelected,'fa-save':loaddata[indexOfelement].isSelected}"></i>
                        {{skills.isSelected}}
                        </a>

                        <a  class="btn btn-info" *ngIf="loaddata[indexOfelement].isSelected"><i  (click)="ClickToEdit(skills,indexOfelement)" Class="fas fa-cancel"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="fas fa-trash"></i></a>
                      </div>
                    </td>
                 
                   

                </tr>
```

and This is my Angular Code

```
 ClickToEdit(skills:any,indexOfelement:number)
  {
    debugger;
    this.loaddata[indexOfelement].isSelected=!this.loaddata[indexOfelement].isSelected;
    console.log(this.loaddata);
    
    
    


  }
```

but click to edit not fire 2nd time

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your click event is placed on the wrong tag.. move it from `<i></i>` to `<a></a>`.

I would use `*ngIf` instead of `ngClass`.

```
<a class="btn btn-info" (click)="ClickToEdit(skills,indexOfelement)">
    <i *ngIf=" edit " class="fa-edit"></i>
    <i *ngIf=" !edit " class="fa-save"></i>
</a>
```

toggle `edit` inside your `ClickToEdit` function